# Nothing appears when drag-and-dropping anything from the Palette in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

## Overview

One day I started a Basic Layout program with a feature in Android Studio but once I was complete with the setup the "Hello World!" Text and other items from the palette that I dragged-and-dropped didn't show up on the design and in the blueprint. I made the items visible and I even changed the settings and the code of the program but nothing worked.

## Image

[I added a text and buttons from the palette, but the items didn't appear as shown in the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0zU8.png)

## Code

Here is some code from the Gradle Scripts:

***Note: I changed the project name in the code.***

***Note: I am using a feature in my program.***

### "build.gradle (Project: Test)" Code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### "build.gradle (Module: app)" Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28



defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.test.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


}

buildTypes {
   release {
       minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation project(':Test_Feature')
implementation project(':base')
}
```

### "build.gradle (Module: base)" Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
baseFeature true
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
application project(':app')
feature project(':Test_Feature')
}
```

### "build.gradle (Module: instantapp)" Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

dependencies {
implementation project(':Test_Feature')
implementation project(':base')
}
```

### "build.gradle (Module: Test_Feature)" Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation project(':base')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

### "settings.gradle (Project Settings)" Code:

```
include ':Test_Feature', ':app', ':base', ':instantapp'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the AppTheme you use to preview, is the same as you defined in res->values->styles.xml.

Sometimes there are problems with displaying things on the preview screen when the themes don't match.

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes when you copy styles from other projects. You can clean and rebuild the project which you can find under build in the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do all of this:

```
Restart Android Studio
Rebuild Solution
Make sure you Target an insert point
```

Comment: I'm a newbie at Android Studio, so what do you mean by "Target the content file"?

Comment: I guess they updated the view. I see just a activity_.xml and a layout.xml file now. Do the first two and make sure you drop in a drop zone, sometimes buttons just disappear if your aim's not so good ;)

Comment: No, I haven't been able to fix it yet, I did some more stuff here and there but nothing pretty much worked.

Comment: I tried to create your app, but there is no Basic Layout program with a feature.. Unless you zip the whole project and put it up somewhere I am afraid, that I can't help you any further. Have you tried creating another quick test app just to see if you are generally hamstrung by some off-worldly bug or it was just a fluke?

Comment: I have tested to see if this issue continued on 2 separate computers, each in a different location, and one computer having a different version of the Windows OS, there were the same issues on those computers too.